# apache tiles 3.0 attribute not overridden in nested definition

Tags: spring-mvc, tiles

I have the following tile definitions

```
<definition name="homePage" extends="basetemplate">
 <put-attribute name="centeredContentSection" value="hometemplate"/>
```

```
<definition name="insidetemplate" templateExpression="/WEB-INF/jsp/templates/centercontentemplate.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="maincomponent" expression="/WEB-INF/jsp/tiles/resource.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="rightcomponent"  expression="/WEB-INF/jsp/tiles/right.jsp"/>
</definition>

<definition name="welcome" extends="basetemplate" >
    <put-attribute name="centeredContentSection" value="insidetemplate"/>
</definition>

<definition name="resourceListing" extends="welcome">
<put-attribute name="maincomponent" expression="/WEB-INF/jsp/tiles/resourcelist.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

In the **resourceListing** definition I specify a **maincomponent** attribute, which I think should override the one defined the  **insidetemplate** definition which is a nested inside **welcome** defintion.  However the value I have specify for **maincomponent** (*/WEB-INF/jsp/tiles/resource.jsp*) does not seem get overridden by the value I specify in **resourceListing** definition.  Is there anyway to make this happpen?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe doesn't sound like correct behaviour.

`Defintion.inherit(definition)` should not be overriding attributes, see `BasicAttributeContext.addMissing(..)`

reference https://github.com/apache/tiles/blob/TILES_3_0_X/tiles-api/src/main/java/org/apache/tiles/BasicAttributeContext.java#L254